# how can I create a condition that matches the first 9 characters of a word with a full name?

Tags: r

How can I create a condition that matches the first 9 characters of the user's name with its full name?

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(full_name = c("alex sainz Lopez", "antonio garcia jimenez", "jorge rivas", "beatriz samanes", "pedro lopez"))

df2 <- data.frame(user = c("sainza", "garciaa", "rivasj", "samanesb", "lopezp"))
```

And I want to create a conditional column that matches the users contained in the second dataframe  with the full name contained in the first dataframe.

I know I can cbind both columns but I need to do it this way. I have thought in a regular expression that matches all the characters except the last character of the user's name with the full_name but I don't know how to write it (I have tried it multiple times but i don't get the result I want)

the result I want is:

```
result <- data.frame(full_name = c("alex sainz Lopez", "antonio garcia jimenez", "jorge rivas", "beatriz samanes", "pedro lopez"),
                     user = c("sainza", "garciaa", "rivasj", "samanesb", "lopezp"))
```

The best solution would be to create a condition that: "if user_name is similar to full_name then result = full_name" but I suppose that is something more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyr` and `separate()` and create the user name from the first df.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 <- data.frame(full_name = c("alex sainz Lopez", "antonio garcia jimenez", "jorge rivas", "beatriz samanes", "pedro lopez"))

df2 <- data.frame(user = c("sainza", "garciaa", "rivasj", "samanesb", "lopezp"))

result <- data.frame(full_name = c("alex sainz Lopez", "antonio garcia jimenez", "jorge rivas", "beatriz samanes", "pedro lopez"),
                     user = c("sainza", "garciaa", "rivasj", "samanesb", "lopezp"))


df3 <- df1 |>  
  tidyr::separate(full_name, into = c("name1","name2","name3"), remove = FALSE) |> 
  mutate(user = paste0(name2, substr(name1,1,1))) |> 
  select(-name1, - name2, -name3)

all.equal(df3, result)
```

In the case that you have a long second name and the user name can only be a max of length 9 you can modify the code to pull the first 8 characters of the second name and the first letter of the first name.

```
df3 <- df1 |>  
  tidyr::separate(full_name, into = c("name1","name2","name3"), remove = FALSE) |> 
  mutate(user = paste0(substr(name2,1,8), substr(name1,1,1))) |> 
  select(-name1, - name2, -name3)
```